# Rollup + typescript doesn't map path alias even using @rollup/plugin-alias

Tags: typescript, rollup

I'm currently using rollup as by bundler.

When I'm trying to build, path aliasing doesn't get mapped...

for example,
[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LugRH.png)

should be parsed into

```
import {FlowType} from 'rightful path to use'
```

I've tried everything I could try.
try to adopt every solution which can be found by googling, but still suffering about this issue..

my tsconfig looks like below

```
//tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    
    "declaration": true,

    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["dom", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "plugins": [
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@models/*" : ["src/models/*"],
      "@constants/*" : ["src/constants/*"],
      "@components/*" : ["src/components/*"],
      "@abi/*" : ["src/abi/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["src/styles/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@assets/*" : ["src/assets/*"],
      "@core/*" : ["src/core/*"],
      "@contexts/*" : ["src/contexts/*"],
      "@hooks/*" : ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@HOC/*" : ["src/HOC/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "test/main.tsx", "test/App.tsx"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "exclude": ["dist","node_modules","test"]
}
```

my rollup.config.js looks as below

```
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import pkg from "./package.json"
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import path from 'path'
import { typescriptPaths } from 'rollup-plugin-typescript-paths'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts'
import tsConfig from './tsconfig.json'
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve"
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel"
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external"
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'
export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    { file: pkg.main, format: "cjs"},
    { file: pkg.module, format: "es" },
  ],
  plugins: [  

    peerDepsExternal(),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
      include: ["src/**/*"]
    }),
    typescript({
    outDir: 'dist',
    tsconfig : './tsconfig.json',
  }),
  scss({fileName: 'bundle.css'}),
  alias({
    resolve: ['.ts','.tsx','.json','.js', '.jsx'],
    entries: [
      {
        find : '@components/*',
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components')
      },
      {
        find : '@constants/*',
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants')
      },
      {
        find : '@models/*',
        replacement  : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/models')
      },
      {
        find : '@abi/*',
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/abi'),
      },
      {
        find : '@styles/*',
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles')
      },
      {
        find : '@utils/*' ,
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname , 'src/utils')
      },
      {
        find : "@assets/*" ,
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname , 'src/assets')
      },
      {
        find : "@core/*" ,
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname, "src/core")
      },
      {
        find : "@contexts/*",
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/contexts"),
      },
      {
        find : "@hooks/*",
        replacement  : path.resolve(__dirname, "src/hooks")
      },
      {
        find : "@HOC/*",
        replacement : path.resolve(__dirname, "src/HOC")
      },
    ],
  }),
  typescriptPaths({
    preserveExtensions: true
  }),
  json()
  ]
};
```